# Directory traversal in groovy does not return all directories

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy

When running a folder traversal in groovy I only get one folder returned instead of the whole tree. So when I have this structure

```
D:
+- Test
+- Test2
+- Test3
```

An run this code

```
def dir = "D:/"

(dir as File).traverse(type: DIRECTORIES) { file ->
    println file.path
}
```

I only get this output

```
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN
```

What's wrong here. The script runs as part of a Jenkins Pipeline

**Additional Info (summary from my comments)**

For testing purpose I run the script on a master on my local machine and jenkins is running under my user which has definitively access to all directories. Actually I only see the first item found i.e. $Recycle.BIN. When I add a D:\$A the corresponding output is D:\$A

When running the script in the jenkins script console, the **output is as expected* (all directories). Also the following call in the pipeline works fine and lists all directories

```
powershell ''' Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name D:/ ''' }
```

Comment: Maybe it's something with permissions of Jenkins agent?

Comment: For testing purpose I run the script on a master on my local machine and jenkins is running under my user which has definitively access to all directories. Actually I only see the first item found i.e. $Recycle.BIN. When I add a D:\$A the corresponding output is

     D:\$A

Comment: When running the script in the jenkins script console, the output is as expected (all directories)

Comment: The following call in the pipeline on the other hand works fine as well and lists all directories

        powershell '''
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name D:/
        '''
    }

Comment: what version of groovy are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.4.15